# Enabling sql syntax highlighting in IDEA for particular string

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea

I have SQL query defined in a class as a static string:

```
private static final String SQL_QUERY = "...sql query...";
```

I am working with database without hibernate.
So if in the same class I have something like this:

```
connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_NEXT_ID);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Then IDEA correctly identifies my `SQL_QUERY` string as a SQL dialect and enables proper highlighting, autocompletion and other sql features for it.

However, if instead of this, I have some helper method which encapsulates this logic in another class, and I just pass there `SQL_QUERY`, so my code looks like:

```
DbHelper.executeSql(SELECT_ALL_ROOMS, DATABASE_NAME);
```

and inside this helper, I do the same things with `connection`, `preparedStatement` and `resultset`, then IDEA doesn't identify my `SQL_QUERY` string as SQL syntax.

Is there any way to enable this sql syntax features for that case? Maybe I can mark `DbHelper.executeSql` with some annotation (or its argument), or maybe I can enable it by marking `SQL_QUERY` with some annotation/comment?

Comment: Did you try @Language("SQL")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Language("SQL")
private static final String SQL_QUERY_STRING = "select * from...";
```

**UPDATE:**

With IntelliJ Plugin: IntelliLang

1. Open Settings > Editor > Language Injections
2. Click the "add button" and select "Java Parameter"
3. In the Language Injection Settings, select SQL (or any other language)
4. In the "Class Methods" field, enter the method you want to identify (executeSql(String sql) in your case). You can open the search window to select via the IDE
5. Your method's query in string must be highlighted as you wish

Comment: great. that works, thanks. However it works only if I mark the String itself, is it possible to make it work marking just the method argument?

Comment: What do you mean by "marking just the method argument"?

Comment: in DbHelper declare method `public void executeSql(@Language("SQL") String sql) {...`

Comment: No, as you can see, there is no String value (String _string"this string value") where you put the annotation. This annotation only works if there is a string value is presented.

Comment: not sure if I understood you. Look, for other strings representing sql, passed directly to `connection.prepareStatement(sql)`(without my helper function) IDEA automatically determines that this string are SQL, without any annotations on the string itself, is it possible to make similar behaviour with custom methods.